# Avoiding .Activate with ActiveX Form Control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm updating a macro that's used in lots of spreadsheets, and it's rather slow. While looking to speed it up, I noticed that at one point it goes through this loop:

```
For each wsLoop in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsLoop.Activate
        With ActiveSheet.Status_Text
            If bStatus = True Then
                .ForeColor = &HC000&
                .Caption = "ONLINE"
            Else
                .ForeColor = &HFF&
                .Caption = "OFFLINE"
            End If
        End With
Next wsLoop
```

Where wsLoop is a worksheet, bStatus is a boolean and Status_Text is the name of an ActiveX label form control on each worksheet.
I know using .Activate is bad practice and can slow things down, so I dropped the `wsLoop.Activate` and changed the next line to `With wsLoop.Status_Text`, but now I get a "Method or data member not found" error message.
What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `.Status_Text`. It doesn't seem to be a property of a worksheet object. When I try to run your code it doesn't work, failing on the line `With ActiveSheet.Status_Text` .with an error to message "Object doesn't support this property or method". What version of Excel are you using? Perhaps this was just added in the most recent version.

Comment: Excel 2010, tested in Excel 2013 as well. "Status_Text" is the name of a caption on the page. I can modify it using ActiveSheet.Status_Text, but not using the wsLoop.Status_Text

Comment: Status_Text is just the name associated with the caption box, so I'm not surprised that nobody else has used that particular name. What I'm confused about is why I can modify it using `ActiveSheet.Captionboxnamehere` but not `Worksheetvariablenamehere.Captionboxnamehere`

Comment: The label is only named in the spreadsheet itself, not in the project anywhere. It is a form control label with the title "Status_Text". I am not using any COM add-ins other than one for Lync messenger (which I can disable without impacting the functionality of the code), and the only addins that I am using are Microsoft's Solver and an addin that I wrote containing a few commonly used macros (tile windows, add IFERROR to cells, etc.)

Comment: All makes sense now -- perhaps you can edit the question to include the crucial piece of information that `Status_Text` is the name of an ActiveX forms control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question which seems to touch on some poorly-documented features of Excel VBA. It seems that maybe the expression `ActiveSheet.Status_Text` is operating as the *name* of the control, with the dot acting as a namespace qualifier, but that in `wsLoop.Status_Text` VBA is interpreting the dot as the method/property access operator and is correctly giving the error message that no such method or property exists. To reproduce the problem, I created a label named `Status_Text` on each sheet and then ran

```
Sub test1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Status_Text.Caption 'fails
    Next ws
End Sub
```

It crashes with the error that you show. One workaround (although just *why* it works is mysterious) is to change the loop index from being a `Worksheet` to a `Variant`:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim ws As Variant
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Status_Text.Caption 'succeeds
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The odd thing about this last example is if you add the line `Debug.Print TypeName(ws)` in the for-each loop it prints `Worksheet` so `ws.Status_Text` works if `ws` is a variant which holds a worksheet but not if `ws` is actually a worksheet. The mystery is in some sense deepened but in another sense lessened when you step through this sub in the debugger, looking at the locals window. The type of `ws` in the loop is described as `Variant/Object/Sheet1` (in the first pass through the loop). The specific sheet seems to be part of the current subtype of the variable.

Another workaround is to use a `For-Next` loop rather than a `For-Each`:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print Worksheets(i).Status_Text.Caption 'succeeds
    Next i
End Sub
```

You could use either of these approaches to get a reference to the label without having to activate the sheet.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I confirmed both approaches worked, and wound up using the For-Next loop as it fit in a bit better with the rest of the module. I edited the question to clarify that it was a form control as well. Thanks so much for your help!